# Asp.net jQuery Validation engine submit issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I am using the [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) in Asp.net MVC everything working for me however when i trying to use in Asp.net Button Validation Messages is come but also the form submited. how to disable the submiting if form is not valid.

```
<link href="~/Content/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#form5").validationEngine({ ajaxFormValidation: true, promptPosition: "bottomLeft", scroll: true, maxErrorsPerField: 1 });
</script>
```

Comment: Show me your asp submit button code, in order to help you...i know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done in this way:

```
$("#<%:yourAspButton.ClientID%>").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if($('#form5').validationEngine('validate'))
   {
     $("#form5").submit();
   }
});
```